Inserting text on either side of colorAxis in gvisGeoChart instead of numbers for Shiny app
I have an app that looks like this 
The numbers on either side of the color axis (1 and 185) are somewhat meaningless. What I would like instead is "Better" and "Worse", like this:

Is there a way to replace the numbers with my desired text? I've looked at this answer but I can't follow it - I need more help on what and where exactly to implement: Google charts geochart - text values in colorAxis
If I can't get the text on either side, then a title on top of the bar would be an improvement at least, but again, I need a more comprehensive answer to the one given here: Google Charts: How to add a caption to the color axis
The relevant code is:
library(shiny)
library(googleVis)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

# Load your data
combined_vul_data <- 
  structure(list(ISO3 = c("AF", "AL", "DZ", "AD", "AO", "AG", "AR", 
                          "AM", "AU", "AT", "AZ", "BS", "BH", "BD", "BB", "BY", "BE", "BZ", 
                          "BJ", "BT"), Name = c("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Andorra", 
                                                "Angola", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Australia", 
                                                "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", 
                                                "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bhutan"
                          ), vul_capacity_Rank_2021 = c(0.709035449, 0.511126182, 0.523332101, 
                                                        NA, 0.740026186, 0.621133795, 0.446088596, 0.462491218, 0.296565054, 
                                                        0.26689445, 0.47917568, NA, 0.453936004, 0.649876424, 0.398904506, 
                                                        0.386808093, 0.27763708, 0.547525366, 0.763503499, 0.635633065
                          )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))


# Define UI for the map
ui <- fluidPage(
      titlePanel(div(span("Country Rankings"), style={'padding-top: 15px'})),
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Vulnerability Map",
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(
                 selectInput("year", "Select Year", choices = 2021, selected = 2021),
                 selectInput("category", "Select Category", 
                             choices = list("Adaptive Capacity" = "vul_capacity"), selected = "vul_vulnerability")
               ),
               mainPanel(
                 htmlOutput("map")
               )
             )
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic for the map
server <- function(input, output) {
   output$map <- renderGvis({
    year <- input$year
    category <- input$category
    
    # Create the column name for the selected year and category
    rank_column <- paste(category, "_Rank_", year, sep = "")
    
    # Filter and prepare the data
    map_data <- combined_vul_data %>%
      select(ISO3, Name, Rank = !!sym(rank_column)) %>%
      mutate(Tooltip = ifelse(is.na(Rank), paste(Name, "- Insufficient data"), paste(Name)))
    
    # Update locationvar column
    map_data <- map_data %>%
      mutate(Location = ifelse(Name %in% c("Congo (Brazzaville)", "Congo (Kinshasa)"), ISO3, Name))
    
    # Determine the range of the Rank values
    min_rank <- min(map_data$Rank, na.rm = TRUE)
    max_rank <- max(map_data$Rank, na.rm = TRUE)
    
    # Create the map
    gvisGeoChart(map_data, locationvar = "Location", colorvar = "Rank",
                 hovervar = "Tooltip",  
                 options = list(colorAxis = paste0("{minValue:", min_rank, ", maxValue:", max_rank, ", colors:['#00FF00', '#FFFF00', '#FF0000']}"),
                                backgroundColor = '#81d4fa', datalessRegionColor = '#f5f5f5',
                                defaultColor = '#f5f5f5',
                                tooltip = "{isHtml: true}",
                                width = "100%",
                                height = "500px"))  
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


Please always provide minimal examples. E.g. the markdown and style parts are not relevant for your problem.

Thanks Jan. I hadn't thought to remove the markdown context and just add the code as if it were only an R app. Got it!

Thank you, this is already better. However, I think you can reduce it to less code, e.g. by removing the CSS which is not needed here.

You're right! I removed that as well as the category context.
